# Create an IPv4 address and increment it with expected output

Tags: python

How can i create an IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and increment it so it gives me the output from 0-255 as 0.0.0.255 then 0.0.255.255,0.255.255.255,255.255.255.255?

Comment: So you want only 259 addresses, the first 256, then those three extras? Or you want to iterate over all 4 billion? Or…?

Comment: @abarnert just the first 256 and then those three extras

Comment: Then take the code in my answer and either `for addr in weird_259(): print(addr)`, or just change the `yield` to a `print`.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using custom functions and go with the `netaddr` package. Just create a `netaddr.IPNetwork` object for network `0.0.0.0/0` and you should be able to get the nth address by referring it as `netaddr.IPNetwork('0.0.0.0/0')[n]` or you can create an iterator as `netaddr.IPNetwork('0.0.0.0/0').iter_hosts()`

You should be able to get it by doing `pip install netaddr`

```
>>> from netaddr import IPNetwork
>>> net = IPNetwork('0.0.0.0/0') 
>>> net[1]                       
IPAddress('0.0.0.1')
>>> str(net[1])
'0.0.0.1'
```

More examples

```
>>> str(net[255])  
'0.0.0.255'        
>>> str(net[256])  
'0.0.1.0'          
>>> str(net[65535])
'0.0.255.255'      
>>> str(net[65536])
'0.1.0.0'
```

Comment: Why go with a third-party library instead of the one that comes in the stdlib and is even easier to use?

Answer (score 0):

The [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html) module in the standard library lets you do arithmetic on IP addresses in the obvious way, and conversion to and from integers, and to and from dotted-quad strings.

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but whatever it is, it's easy.

For example, here's an iterator over all 4 billion IPv4 addresses:

```
def all_addrs():
    for i in range(0, 1<<32):
        yield ipaddress.IPv4Address(i)
```

Or, if you prefer:

```
def all_addrs():
    addr = ipaddress.IPv4Address(0)
    while True:
        yield addr
        try:
            addr += 1
        except ValueError:
            return
```

Or, if you want to iterate the first 256, then do three special addresses after that:

```
def weird_259():
    for i in range(256):
        yield ipaddress.IPv4Address(i)
    yield ipaddress.IPv4Address('0.0.255.255')
    yield ipaddress.IPv4Address('0.255.255.255')
    yield ipaddress.IPv4Address('255.255.255.255')
```

---

If you want to do other things, read the docs for `IPv4Address`. Notice that you can construct an address from:

1. A string in decimal-dot notation…
2. An integer…
3. An integer packed into a `bytes` object of length 4 (most significant octet first).

So, let's say you want to make one out the octets 0, 127, 255, 255. How could you do that? First, you create a bytes with those values:

```
bytes([0, 127, 255, 255])
```

… and then you create an address with those bytes:

```
ipaddress.IPv4Address(bytes([0, 127, 255, 255]))
```

If you want to, you can wrap that up in a function:

```
def makeaddr(a, b, c, d):
    return ipaddress.IPv4Address(bytes([a, b, c, d]))
```

So, if you wanted the 256 addresses of the form `0.0.0.x`, and the 256 of the form `0.0.x.255`, and `0.x.255.255`, and `x.255.255.255`, that's trivial:

```
def make_1024():
    for x in range(256):
        yield makeaddr(0, 0, 0, x)
    for x in range(256):
        yield makeaddr(0, 0, x, 255)
    for x in range(256):
        yield makeaddr(0, x, 255, 255)
    for x in range(256):
        yield makeaddr(x, 255, 255, 255)
```

And if you want to print them out in the default (decimal-dot) notation, just `print` them:

```
for addr in make_1024():
    print(addr)
```

Comment: for i in range(0, 2 ** 24): # modify to 2 ** 32 if you want to generate output to 255.255.255.255
    byte3 = i & 0xff
    byte2 = i & 0xff00
    byte1 = i & 0xff0000
    byte0 = i & 0xff000000
    print('%d.%d.%d.%d' % (byte0 >> 24, byte1 >> 16, byte2 >> 8, byte3)) # this is what i wanna do but i want to use the ipaddress module or some easier way of doing this compared to the above one.

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid I don’t understand what you mean by that comment. What does my answer not explain that you need to do?

Comment: sir, i used your def weird_259() code and was able to iterate the last octet of 0.0.0.0 how do i iterate the other octets in the same manner?

Comment: Your comment on the question says you want "just the first 256 and then those three extras". That's exactly what the code gives you. I don't understand what you're trying to do here. I tried asking for clarification, made sure my code did what you said you wanted after you clarified, and apparently that isn't what you actually wanted, so… I don't know how to help you.

Comment: @abarnet ok let's do this again forget everything you have read about my posts till this point and kindly read what I am about to type so there's no ambiguity left:- I used your code and it iterated the last octet "**0.0.0.This**" one by one till 255 which i wanted now my query is, can i iterate the other octets like this as well "**0.0.This.255**" "**0.This.255.255**" "**This.255.255.255**" so in the end i get **255.255.255.255** by iterating each one from 0 to 255. Hope that made it clear.

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid Does my edited answer explain things?

Comment: yes it did! ty so much you have no idea how much this helped me THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Range from 0 to 16777216 (which is 2 ** 24, as your title requesting for `0.255.255.255`, or 4294967296 which is 2 ** 32 as your question body requesting for `255.255.255.255`), then bitwise AND `0xff`, `0xff00`, `0xff0000`, `0xff000000` to extract the corresponding bits, and shift them right to print with format.

```
for i in range(0, 2 ** 24): # modify to 2 ** 32 if you want to generate output to 255.255.255.255
    byte3 = i & 0xff
    byte2 = i & 0xff00
    byte1 = i & 0xff0000
    byte0 = i & 0xff000000
    print('%d.%d.%d.%d' % (byte0 >> 24, byte1 >> 16, byte2 >> 8, byte3))
```

Comment: Yes!! This is what i meant to do but do you know some other way of doing this like using some module for it?

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid What do you mean of "module"? I think the top vote answer (yes, I top vote that, too) which uses `netaddr` package is "using some module", however you commented that you need a built-in package?

Comment: @TheCharismaticSid Are you looking for a built-in package which can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `struct` lib.

```
import struct

n = 257

y1, y2, y3, y4 = struct.Struct('<I').pack(n & 0xFFFFFFFF)

print("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}".format(y4,y3,y2,y1)) # OUTPUT: 0.0.1.1
```

`I` stands for big integer (4 bytes), `<` stands for big endian (bytes position).
Then you format the bytes in the right order. Increase or decrease `n` for having different ip addresses